# PhoneGap images occasionally failing to load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, phonegap

I am building a social app which loads many images at a time using PhoneGap, and I've been encountering an issue where images occasionally fail to load. The only difficult thing in diagnosing the problem is it happens very infrequently and unpredictably.

I have ruled out other factors as it works perfectly using desktop or the mobile browser directly loading http://192.168.X.X:3000/ and have never had it fail, however, when using PhoneGap it seems to fail about 1% of the time.

Is this possibly a memory management problem? Or a known common issue with PhoneGap? Any input would be appreciated.

Comment: I personally never had this issue with phonegap and the only thing i could think of is the remote server (where you store your images) could fail or the device memory issue. Nothing to do with the phonegap. one thing you can do is to optimize your images.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. It had to do with not setting the height of the images, and scaling them. After setting the height on all images, for some reason that fixed the issue. Not sure if that is a bug in webkit or something, but now I can load over 100 pages with no images failing.